# Error PackageManager Console

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, powershell

When I Open my `PackageManagerConsole`. I have the *problem*

> Join-Path : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type
>   'System.String' required by parameter 'ChildPath'. Specified method is
>   not supported. At
>   C:\Users\renan.carlos\Source\Repos\CodingCraft\ExerciciosCodingCraft\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0\tools\init.ps1:13
>   char:57 + ... rPackageDirectory = Join-Path $packageDirectory
>   $compilerPackage.Name + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo :
>   InvalidArgument: (:) [Join-Path], ParameterBindingException +
>   FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.JoinPathCommand
>
> Join-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is
>   null. At
>   C:\Users\renan.carlos\Source\Repos\CodingCraft\ExerciciosCodingCraft\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0\tools\init.ps1:14
>   char:44 + ... erPackageToolsDirectory = Join-Path
>   $compilerPackageDirectory 'tools' + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ +
>   CategoryInfo : InvalidData: (:) [Join-Path],
>   ParameterBindingValidationException + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.JoinPathCommand

What is and as to solve this problem?

Answer (score 13):

Update to DotNetCompilerPlatform 1.0.1 [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform/1.0.1)

And also make sure you run nuget 3.3 (it comes with update one of visual studio 2015, or you can go to the Tools-Extensions and Updates)

Comment: I did what you suggested but the problem still persists. Do you have any other suggestions. Thank you.